# Parse XML In Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, azure, mobile

I have some XML data that I am looking to parse in Azure Mobile Services using Javascript.

Any ideas on how to do this?  Ive tried DOMParser but I get "DOMParser is not defined at Request._callback" and from what I understand I'd have to add some reference using "var parser = require('XXX').DomParser;".

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I try to stick to JSON, so I don't parse XML that much, but I read good things about [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js). It's a node module, so you can use that in your Mobile App. Give it a shot.